# can i reorder Android text selection toolbar item(Process_text)?

Tags: android

[image]

My app is end of the list in the toolbar.how i set my app to first place to the toolbar avoiding scrolling.

Comment: I do not think that you have control over that, sorry.

Comment: i feel it  but wps memo app always top . translate also under it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Google maps can, or is that an exception given that it's considered as a system app

Comment: @polendina: I don't know that it is Maps that is doing that. It only takes effect if the highlighted text is an address, in my light testing. My guess is that the OS is recognizing the address format and is looking for mapping apps that might handle the address.

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess the same. As `Web Search` is also universal. Can that behavior still be overridden?

Comment: If you are asking for context menus in your own app, you can suppress the context menu, but I don't recall whether you can change the menu content. If you are asking for context menus in other apps (as lava did), then AFAIK the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

**Temporary Workaround**
please don't downvote.I could utilize this answer.
[android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d2acc476d07529ad847f41c79af896d9a6f40d80/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java#7755)

@Mike's hint

[image]
i just change package name from com.shersoft.fdserv to ab.shersoft.fdserv
based on the mike hint .i could understand that the menu is showing based on the order of package name.so **it's temp solution** new app with package name fit will come forward.

[image]

So It come to first position.

[image]

Comment: Can that be further enhanced to override the application's own items i.e. some applications like Chrome has its own item `web search` appended to the main context menu, forcing the user to expand the arrow for additional selections including my app, which is quite inconvenient